# Virtual eth-adapter in networking-configuration

Tags: debian, networking

I have on my Debian en eth0-interface and I need the interface to listen to other IP's.
I know I can create it with the following command

```
ifconfig eth0:1 10.10.10.20/24
```

With this command everything works fine and the new interface listens to the given IP.

My problem is, when I want to add this virtual eth-interface into the network-configuration like this

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
         address 10.10.10.10
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         network 10.10.10.0
         broadcast 10.10.10.255
         gateway 10.10.10.1
         # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
         dns-nameservers 10.10.10.1

iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 10.10.10.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 10.10.10.255
```

and then restart the network with

```
 /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

none of the both interfaces come up again.

why is that? is my configuration wrong?

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake.

You need to add a line above the interface-start-line and add a vlan-raw-device:

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 10.10.10.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 10.10.10.255
        vlan-raw-device eth0
```

With this, it works fine ;)

Comment: I prefer adding a line to the first eth0 stanza: `post-up ip addr add 10.10.10.20/32 dev eth0`. Also the `vlan-raw-device` line makes so sense at all in your answer.